# Neo4j Cypher RETURN with OPTIONAL MATCH in pattern comprehensions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use the following Neo4j Cypher `RETURN` statement with pattern comprehensions:

```
[ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria
```

which works fine.

I'd like to extend it a little bit to return more information, to something like this:

```
[ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) WITH c1, vg1 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (c1)-[rc1t:CONTAINS]->(c1t:Translation {deleted: false}) 
    WHERE ($iso6391 IS NOT null AND c1t.iso6391 = $iso6391) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1, translation: c1t} ] AS weightedCriteria
```

but such a query fails with `org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Cypher execution failed with code 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError` on `WITH`

Is it possible to implement with pattern comprehensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern comprehension is like a for loop but simplified and compact form. So you cannot put another MATCH inside of it.  Try below query and let us know if it works or not.

```
MATCH (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD)  
OPTIONAL MATCH (c1)-[rc1t:CONTAINS]->(c1t:Translation {deleted: false}) 
WHERE $iso6391 IS NOT null AND c1t.iso6391 = $iso6391
RETURN collect({criterion: c1, relationship: vg1, translation: c1t}) AS weightedCriteria
```

Answer (score 1):

Since pattern comprehension is a form of a subquery, you can use complete subquery syntax to achieve what you want.

Here, I am assuming you started with `c1`

```
CALL {
  WITH c1
  MATCH (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) 
  WITH c1, vg1 
  OPTIONAL MATCH (c1)-[rc1t:CONTAINS]->(c1t:Translation {deleted: false}) 
  WHERE ($iso6391 IS NOT null AND c1t.iso6391 = $iso6391)
  RETURN {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1, translation: c1t}
}
```